# Is it dead? - Raspberry Pi 2 B

Tags: gpio, pi-2

I was connecting the UART connections onto my Pi to try crack a Cisco Merkai.

Unfortunately, the ground connection hit a 5 V GPIO (hit GPIO2 or 4). My Raspberry Pi 2 boots however it does not do anything. The LEDs stay lit red and green solid.

The SD card that was in it at the time is fine as I have gotten it to boot by using my friend's Pi 3.

Is there any thing else I can do to determine the issue or will it better off giving my Pi 2 the send off it deserves and upgrade to a Pi 3?

I just want to see why it won't boot rather than fixing it... just making that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If powering  the Pi via the micro-USB socket, all RPis except Zeros have a self resetting polyfuse which should prevent damage.

In the case of a Zero or powering other RPis via the GPIO header there is fuse provided. Shorting the 5 volt and ground pins will cause distress to the PSU which can kill it.

Which is why I recommend to unplug the Pi before doing any wiring. Then double check your work and then, only then, apply power to the Pi.

Comment: Is there any resistor I can check to see if it is blown?

Comment: @KyleMcCann you could take a look at the polyfuse as shown here,https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=156144 but there is a good chance it is still functional as the leds would have not turned on had it been damaged. If my answer has helped you please do not hesitate to click the checkmark to the left of my answer to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: I am unable to boot any distro, would that be due to the polyfuse? It has been over 24 hours...

Comment: if the leds were not working then id say it might be the polyfuse, if like in your case they are, you probably burnt the cpu.  If my answer has helped you please do not hesitate to click the checkmark to the left of my answer to mark it as the correct answer.